# How to read characteristic from BLE device until it have results?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an app that should to connect with a BLE device.
This device, storage the information that retreive from its sensors in a queque.

It is possibile that at the time X, the queque of this device have 100 items value.

Now my Android application must to connect of it, and download the data of the characteristic untile the queque of devis is empty.

This is the code that I use to read one value at time. How can I change it to get all data ?

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        //mSensors = db.getAllSensorTypes();
        //BLUETOOTH LOW ENERGY NON SUPPORTATO
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        //VERIFICO SE IL BLUETOOTH DEL DISPOSITIVO E' ABILITATO
        //OPPURE NO. SE NON è ABILITATO DEVO CHIEDERE ALL'UTENTE DI ATTIVARLO
        // Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        tvBLE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBLE);
        ibDownload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibDownload);

        //ibDownload.setEnabled(false);

        ibDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(currDevice!=null){
                    GattClientCallback gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
                    mGatt = currDevice.connectGatt(getBaseContext(), false, gattClientCallback);
                    scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
                }
                refreshListView();
            }
        });

        // Bluetooth is supported?
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth non supportato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("result", result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                            connectToDevice(device);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        String nomeDispositivo = device.getName();
        if (mGatt == null && device.getName()!= null && device.getName().equals("Diabesity care")) {
            currDevice = device;
            ibDownload.setEnabled(true);
            ibDownload.setImageResource(R.drawable.download_ok);
            //mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
            //scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }



    private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            Log.i("tag","onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
                logError("Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
                logError("Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            }

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.i("INFO","Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                setConnected(true);
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.i("INFO","Disconnected from device");
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i("INFO","Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics = BluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
                logError("Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }


            ReadQueue = new ArrayList<>();
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characterist:  matchingCharacteristics) {
                ReadQueue.add(characterist);
            }
            ReadQueueIndex = 1;
            ReadCharacteristics(ReadQueueIndex);


        }

        private void ReadCharacteristics(int index){
            mGatt.readCharacteristic(ReadQueue.get(index));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i("INFO","Characteristic read successfully");
                //readCharacteristic(characteristic);

                SensorData mSenData = new SensorData();
                mSenData.setValue(characteristic.getStringValue(0));
                //TO-DO HO COMMENTATO QUESTA RIGA DI CODICE
                // mSenData.setIdType(st.getId());
                mSenData.setIdType(++id);
                mSenData.setCharacteristic(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                mSenData.setValueTimestamp(db.getDateTime());
                //inserisco i dati nel db
                db.insertSensorData(mSenData);


                ReadQueue.remove(ReadQueue.get(ReadQueueIndex));
                if (ReadQueue.size() >= 0) {
                    ReadQueueIndex--;
                    if (ReadQueueIndex == -1) {
                        Log.i("Read Queue: ", "Complete");
                    }
                    else {
                        ReadCharacteristics(ReadQueueIndex);
                    }
                }
                //refreshListView();

            } else {
                logError("Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                // Trying to read from the Time Characteristic? It doesnt have the property or permissions
                // set to allow this. Normally this would be an error and you would want to:
                // disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: How does the android client know how large the queue is?

Comment: The Android client don't know how many items are in the queque. The solution is get data until the BLE Device return items